# How to manage multiple build target configurations with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to think through how to design a new project build system.
I want to use CMake to compile for Windows and Linux. I want to have Release and Debug builds, which are pretty straight forward.

The problem is that I will want to deploy this software for multiple hardware projects over the course of the next few years. This means that I will have pre-processor definitions to turn on/off and or alter functionality in my C++ program. The bulk of the code will remain the same. I will also want to link configuration specific libraries. A current legacy project uses a header with a list of defines and then links all possible project dependencies.

An example configuration header:

```
// projects.h

//#define project1
//#define project2
#define project3
```

Which means that to change hardware/project configurations you have to edit this file to make sure the correct hardware configuration is selected.
What I want to do is to have a configuration for each project which can also be configured for Release or Debug build.

Is there any advice on how to more optimally deal with this in CMake?

Comment: Does [#cmakedefine](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) would work for you ? This way you can tell CMake which project configuration you want to build and it will define the constants accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to keep it as simple as possible for as long as possible.

If you are with CMake now, you have out of the box machinery to determine what platform you are running on. You can just use it to set conditional build flags and preprocessor definitions to drive the rest of the build process.

If you grow out of CMake, but still want to stay in the world of meta build systems you can look towards [Waf](https://waf.io), it's more modular then CMake and is written in Python, and has both declarative and imperative syntax, so kind of future proof.

Comment: In the original question, there is nothing that CMake can't do. Waf is not widespread, and I would stay with what is widely used.

Comment: @jcm - I only suggested it as a fallback if for whatever reason CMake is not a fit. In my experience, CMake can be just too solid/opinionated.